# StringBuilder pops up everytime when I run a program in eclipse (debug mode)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, stringbuilder, mode

I have just refactored my project with many class file changes and when I start debugging the first entry class having main in eclipse, it always pops up StringBuilder with no source found and I have to do 100s of F8 to pass through that. I am not sure if that was because I made my code changes related to String or StringBuilder.

I dont know why is it not stopping at first line of my program though, I have a breakpoint there.

I tried changing JDK 1.6 from 1.7, still facing same experience.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Narayana.V

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you clear all your breakpoints.  You may have one in the StringBuilder class itself.

Comment: I was suspecting that too but No, I dont have any break point in there. Also, I switched jdks and seeing the same issue, so I dont think there could be a breakpoint in two StringBuilders each.